# How to send follow up emails in Automation Studio to the subscribers who didn't click the initial email within 24 hours?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

Currently, we are sending our initial transactional email through API. However, the next requirement is to send follow up emails to the subscribers who didnt open the initial email within 24 hours . As we are planning to do this through Journey builder, the entry source for the journey should be a data extension that is fired through Automation Studio. Could someone help me out with the Automation studio portion as in what shall be written in SQL activities to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Since your initial email is triggered and NOT sent from Journey Builder - you could do the following:

Run a daily Automation Studio activity to find customers who didn't click the initial email from the previous 24-48 hour period, and add them to a Journey Builder activity that sends them a follow up.

Query to add customers to Journey Builder based on "not clicked initial email":

```sql
SELECT
initial.SubscriberKey
,initial.EmailAddress
,initial.OtherFields
FROM [Initial_API_Email_DE] as initial
INNER JOIN _Sent as sent ON sent.SubscriberKey = initial.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
   SubscriberKey
   ,JobID
   ,EventDate
   FROM _Open 
   WHERE JobID = "##Your Initial Email Job ID##"
   AND EventDate >= dateadd(dd,-2,getdate())
) as open ON open.SubscriberKey = initial.SubscriberKey
WHERE sent.JobID = "##Your Initial Email Job ID##"
AND sent.EventDate BETWEEN dateadd(dd,-2,getdate()) AND dateadd(dd,-1,getdate())
AND open.SubscriberKey IS NULL
```

**SQL Explanation**:
It is checking your "Initial Email Data Extension" against the _Sent data view to see who was sent the Initial Email 24-48 hours ago. It then checks _Open to see if any of those people have also Opened the email, and only returns the subscribers who didn't open.

Now you have some SQL that selects the Subscribers that didn't open the email and puts them in a Data Extension, you should create a Journey Builder activity (using that DE as an entry source). There are plenty of articles to step you through that process.

**References**:
[_Sent Data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5)
[_Open Data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi Cameron, Thanks for the response. Could you please tell me where can i get my Job ID if I am sending the email through API ?

Comment: The JobID can be found in your send reporting tab in Email Studio. For triggered (API) sends, make sure you find the correct/current version in the triggered send reporting folder.

Comment: Apologies but I couldn't find anything called Send reporting tab in Email Studio

Comment: Apologies; you want the Sends option under the Tracking Tab in Email Studio.

Comment: That is the problem actually. The Send definitions created through API aren't listed here.

Comment: Are you using the new-ish transactional API? Or one of the older triggered APIs?

Comment: New Transactional API

Comment: Thanks Sourab Mund, I can see you’ve had responses on your other question regarding the JobID with the new transactional API. The new transactional API is not designed for this kind of activity; it’s meant for fire and forget tasks. You will need to change the client’s implementation to an API method that allows for tracking (such as the standard triggered send definitions or the Journey Builder entry event, as commented by Daman.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers of email send-outs is not too high, there is another easier way to do this.
1. Send your transactional email via Journey Builder by inject into journey using API event.
2. Add wait for 1-2 days as per need.
3. Add engagement split activity and send reminder email on basis of open/click etc. Setup in engagement split activity.

Comment: We need to suggest the client the approach of using Journey Builder for the initial email when nothing works. Thanks